Postgres query is returning a new record for every new price entry (Should be the latest price only)
I'm creating a filter for Brazilian REITs, my goal is to get the last recorded price for each REIT and use it as a source for some calculations.
My goal (with a single price record for each REIT):

Actual result: (2 price records for VISC and one for GARE):

my actual query:
select
    r.ticker,
    rp.price,
    SUM(rq.amount) as quota_amount,
    SUM(rq.amount * rq.price) / SUM(rq.amount) as average_price,
    CONCAT(ROUND((rp.price - AVG(rq.price)) / rp.price * 100,   2), '%') as variation_percentage,
    SUM(rq.amount) * rp.price as balance,
    SUM(rq.amount * rq.price) as total_invested,
    (SUM(rq.amount) * rp.price) - (SUM(rq.amount * rq.price)) as currency_variation,
    rp.registered_at as price_registration_date
from
    reit_quote rq
inner join reit r on
    r.id = rq.reit_id
inner join reit_price rp on
    rq.reit_id = rp.reit_id
group by
    r.ticker,
    rp.price,
    rp.registered_at
order by rp.registered_at desc

DATABASE: postgres

I got the solution:
WITH latest_prices AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (reit_id)
    reit_id,
    price,
    registered_at
FROM
    reit_price
ORDER BY
    reit_id,
    registered_at DESC
)
SELECT
  r.ticker,
  lp.price,
  SUM(rq.amount) AS quota_amount,
  SUM(rq.amount * rq.price) / SUM(rq.amount) AS average_price,
  CONCAT(ROUND((lp.price - AVG(rq.price)) / lp.price * 100, 2), '%') AS variation_percentage,
  SUM(rq.amount) * lp.price AS balance,
  SUM(rq.amount * rq.price) AS total_invested,
  (SUM(rq.amount) * lp.price) - (SUM(rq.amount * rq.price)) AS currency_variation
FROM reit_quote rq
INNER JOIN reit r ON r.id = rq.reit_id
INNER JOIN latest_prices lp ON lp.reit_id = rq.reit_id
GROUP BY r.ticker, lp.price, lp.registered_at

